# Trouble with Integrating a Matrix-Valued Function in Quadpy

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I'm trying to integrate a matrix exponential in quadpy and I'm having some trouble understanding what the shape of the output of my function should be so that the integration works properly. Here's a simple example I'm trying to get to work:

```
import numpy as np
import quadpy
from scipy import linalg

def f(x):
    return linalg.expm(np.array([[x[0],0],[0,x[0]]],float))

I = quadpy.c1.gauss_legendre(10).integrate(f, [0.0, 1.0])
print(I)
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
Expected the function return value to be of shape (2, 10), but got shape (2, 2) instead.
```

How should I adjust my function so that the integration works properly?

Comment: Check the the shape of the input `x`, this should give you some hint. Also have a look [here](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy/wiki/Dimensionality-of-input-and-output-arrays).

Comment: By the way, I filed a but report for vectorizing `expm` just [yesterday](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/13943)! It's not available in scipy yet, so you'll have  to do some looping.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer Would I be able to use the matrix exponential function in TensorFlow (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/expm) with quadpy? It looks like it's vectorized unlike the scipy version.

Comment: I fixed the error message to be more understandable now. Will release in a few minutes. In quadpy you can use anything, provided you return f(x) with the correct shape.

Answer (score 0):

The output of `f` has to have shape `(2, 2, 10)`. You can achieve that, for example, by looping over all `x` (which has shape `(10,)`) and filling in the array. There is also a [scipy bug](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/12838) concerned with vectorizing `expm`.